# Real Analysis proof: the nth root of a converges to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to understand a proof in an analysis book. (I am a beginner).Prove that $${\sqrt [n]a}$$ converges to 1, in the case that 0<a<1

I know that the goal is to show that:
$$|\sqrt [n]a-1|$$ = $$1-{\sqrt [n]a}<E $$, so that means that
$$1-E < {\sqrt [n]a}$$
and $${(1-E)^n} < a$$
So I have to find an N, so that if n>N then $$1-{\sqrt [n]a}<E $$

I dont understand this part of the proof:
if $$E \lt 1$$, $${(1-E)^n}$$ converges to zero, so there is an index N, such that if n>N then $${(1-E)^n} \lt a $$
will be true.

Why E must be less than 1? And why $${(1-E)^n}$$ converges to zero?

Comment: The definition of limit requires "for any $E > 0$". However you can just focus on any $1 > E' > 0$. Because if the absolute value of the difference is smaller than $E' < 1$, it certainly will be smaller than any $E \geq 1$. You want to consider $1 > E' > 0$ to make sure $1-E' >0$, and avoid the discussion of the sign. For your second question you can check theorem 3.20 (e): https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~agboola/teaching/2021/winter/122A/rudin.pdf

Comment: It's spelled, "prove".

Comment: Title - It's the $n$th root of $a$, not the square root ($2$nd root) of $n$.

Comment: Sorry. :) English is not my mother tongue. I also had a feeling that it was wrong gramatically.

Comment: Oh I read about that, and understood the proof, its the Bernoully inequility!

Comment: hint, note that $(1-\epsilon)^n > 1 - \epsilon n$. (fixed for your case)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\frac{1}{a}-1$. Then $\alpha>0$ and $a=\frac{1}{1+\alpha }$. For $n \in \mathbb N^+$, the binomial expansion shows that $$(1+\frac{\alpha}{n})^n \ge 1+\alpha$$ $$1+\frac{\alpha}{n} \ge (1+\alpha)^{1/n}$$ $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}} \le (\frac{1}{1+\alpha})^{1/n}$$ $$1 \ge a^{1/n} \ge \frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}} \ge 1--\frac{\alpha}{n}$$ Take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Its difficult for me. I am really a beginner. So we already know that $${(x^n}$$ approaches to zero, if $$|x| \lt 1$$. In order to be true for $${(1-E)^n}$$, E must be less than 1, and greater than zero. But then (1-E)^n approaches zero, so we already proved that it converges to 0. So we know that theres is an N, such that for all n>N, (1-E)^n<a. Its true for a, beause 0<a<1. But if that is true, then the things above are also true. But then dont we just showed for the case, when 1>E>0?

Comment: I think I understand. Because  E'<1<=E the inequlity above will be true also for E. Ok its easy.

Comment: But the latest answer is complicated for me. I dont even know how to take the limit as n approaches infinity